# wp_dropdown_categories() works correctly but the list is not filtered in admin for custom post type. What is the problem?

Tags: categories, filters

When the filter is executed the correct query is passed as
`edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=banner&action=-1&m=0&banner_cat=31&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1`

however the items list remains the same and shows all items from all categories.

[image: screen shot]

### the coding

**Select field**

```php
add_action('restrict_manage_posts', function($posttype) 
{
    if( $posttype != 'banner' )
        return;
    $tax = 'banner_cat';
    
    $selected = (isset($_GET[$tax]) ? $_GET[$tax] : '');
    wp_dropdown_categories([
    'show_option_all' => get_taxonomy($tax)->label,
    'taxonomy'        => $tax,
    'name'            => $tax,
    'orderby'         => 'name',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'selected'        => $selected,
    'hide_empty'      => false,
    'hierarchical' => true
    ]);
});
```

A quest for solution has returned the below filter but I don't see the logic and using it has not corrected the results.

```php
global $pagenow;
                
if( $pagenow == 'edit.php' ) 
{
    add_filter('parse_query', function($query) 
    {
        $tax = 'banner_cat';
        $q = $query->query_vars;
        if( isset($_GET['filter_action']) ) {
            $term = get_term_by('id', $_GET[$tax], $tax);
            $q[$tax] = $term->slug;
        }
    });
}
```

**Do I need to run** `new  WP_Query()` and rebuild the HTML table? It seems like a query overkill so I figure there is a hook or method that is needed.

### Edit to show post_type and taxonomy registration

```php
add_action('init', function() {

register_post_type('banner', [
'public' => true,
'rewrite' => false,
'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-admin-page',
'show_admin_column' => true,
'exclude_from_search' => true,
'publicly_queryable' => true,
'hierarchical' => true,
'description' => 'Handle advertising banners',
'query_var' => true,
'taxonomies'=>['banner_cat'],
'supports' => [
    'title',
    'thumbnail',
    'author',
    'excerpt',
    //'editor'
    ],
'labels' => [
    'name'=>'Banners',
    'add_new'=>'Add Banner',
    'archives' => 'Categories'
    ],
]);

register_taxonomy('banner_cat', 'banner', [
    'labels' => [
    'name' => 'Categories', 
    'singular_name' => 'Category',
    'parent_item' => 'Parent Category',
    'parent_item_color' => 'Parent Category:',
    'edit_item' => 'Edit Category',
    'update_item' => 'Update Category',
    'add_new_item' => 'Add Category',
    'new_item_name' => 'Category Name',
    'menu_name' => 'Category',
    'all_items'=>'All Categories',
    ],
    'public'=>true,
    'hierarchical'      => true,
    'show_ui'           => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'query_var'         => true,
    'rewrite'           => false,
]);

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Do I need to run** `new  WP_Query()` and rebuild the HTML table?

*No, you absolutely do not need to!* And actually, you don't even need to hook on `parse_query` (which BTW, is an **action** and not a filter).

All you need to do is set your categories dropdown's `name` to the taxonomy name/slug, which you've already done so, and **set the `value_field` [argument](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_dropdown_categories/#parameters) to `slug`**, and then WordPress will automatically filter the posts based on the selected `banner_cat` term.

So just remove the entire `add_filter('parse_query', ...)` part from your code, and set the `value_field` like so:

```php
wp_dropdown_categories([
    'show_option_all' => get_taxonomy($tax)->label,
    'taxonomy'        => $tax,
    'name'            => $tax,   // use the taxonomy name/slug
    'orderby'         => 'name',
    'order'           => 'DESC',
    'selected'        => $selected,
    'hide_empty'      => false,
    'hierarchical'    => true,
    'value_field'     => 'slug', // set to 'slug'
]);
```

Comment: I should have noted all the other methods I tried, including `value_field=>slug` which still did not perform the filter action. I had already rid the `parse_query` action (using filter was an act of desperation) because it did not have the applicable logic. With slug the query string is `edit.php?s&post_status=all&post_type=banner&action=-1&m=0&banner_cat=side-banners&filter_action=Filter&paged=1&action2=-1` but still all items from all cats are returned.

Comment: In that case, then please edit your question and add the post type and taxonomy registration code you used.

Comment: The question has been updated to show the taxonomy and post_type registration coding.

Comment: I have spotted the error. Your initial response is indeed correct. I had it as a typo error in my earlier tests as `value_feld=>slug` (missing i) and just now realized that it had worked when I added that element again after your reply. I only paid attention to the query URL and didn't realize that the result was correct. Thanks.

Comment: And I was just about to submit my reply which asked you to check for any typo in your code  because your registration code is good, so I don't see why would `'value_field' => 'slug'` not work :) Anyway, I'm glad you've resolved the issue.